# verifying imagemagick is installed through browser url

Tags: php, ubuntu, server, imagemagick

we installed **imagemagick** in our server using `pecl install imagick` is there any way we can check it is succesfuly installed or not in server ?

can we paste any url in browser and check whether it is installed or not?

please help me to find solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are getting confused @nsdlfefinedieicbe Imagemagick is a stand alone program and Imagick is a php API for Imagemagick. Which do you want to know is installed?

Comment: Looking at the link I do not think Imagick is installed. There should be a section with the Imagick details if it was.

Comment: @Bonzo we have some thing like this : https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/503301/3974813/BtIlNVawQhZ0byO/imagemagic.png

Comment: That is Imagemagick @nsdlfefinedieicbe  which you can use with exec() and the command line.